# How was this css effect achieved?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ran into two different website few days back, which was a responsive site but images had different css rules. I'm not sure if only css was used or some javascript. For example in responsive sites, when a window is made small, the images also turns small, so does the text and with different break points size of text can be manipulated.

1) What I saw was on the first website, the height of the image remained the same but the image within it shrunk when the screen was made small. I can compare this to a camera's zoom in and zoom out effect. When the window was made small, the image zoomed out. when the window size was made big, the image zoomed in (all the while height remained the same).

2) On the second website, I noticed that when the screen was made small, the image(100% width) slid to the left of the screen, but the height remained the same.

Two different websites:

---

[image]

Wondering how this was done?

Comment: With media queries or max/min width? Have you tried reproducing this?

Comment: `img { height: 500px; max-width: 100%;}` or `img { height: 500px; width: auto; }` not sure how you want.

Comment: I tried with `object fit`,  `max-width` and height in pixels. I'm not able to reproduce the same effect.

Comment: The best way to figure this sort of thing out is to use your browser's developer console and inspect the elements, view the applied styles, etc.  There's a variety of ways these effects could be achieved, and it truly depends on your needs, markup, etc. in order to determine which one you should use.

Comment: Can people post why this is a bad question? And this is not off topic he is asking how this is made on different websites. Using html css, javascript etc.

Comment: What are the sites? Use chrome inspector to see the css... No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured this out:

```
.somediv {
    background-image: url("baloon.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is simply images with `fluid-height` and `fixed-height`.

In the first example image is set to `max-width: 100%` and `height: auto` which resizes according to screen size.

In the second example there is a container `div` with `max-width: 100%` and `overflow: auto` which simple does not allow the image surpass window size and you have an image with fixed height.

Fluid height:

```css
.fluid-height{
  max-width: 100%:
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Fluid width and height</p>

<img class="fluid-height" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491308056676-205b7c9a7dc1?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a4dc6385e23451fd8aa3458688757100&auto=format&fit=crop&w=4506&q=80">
```

Fixed height:

```css
div{
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img{
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<p>Fixed height</p>

<div>
<img class="fixed-height" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522206052224-9c5ad951dd74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6276d94baf7d9a4b6962be8d9e8aeb4b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=8100&q=80">
</div>
```

Comment: I kind of got the first one: I actually added `background image` and then added `padding-top` and `padding-below`. It gives zoom in and out effect.Can play around with this and make it more creative. The only thing is to have a large image for this like scenic backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

## Responsive scaling on websites

Right side image scales with the div that surrounds it.
|container
--|image
|end container

- Setting `width:50%;` on the image makes it take up 50% of the container.
- The container scales with the viewPort or window.
  The container has `display: inline-block;` so that other elements can fit next to it.

Example:

- **red** element is the **container**,
- **blue** represents the **window**.

Javascript is only there to scale the blue window on button press.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let counter = 1;
  let button = document.getElementById("scale");
  let tmpWindow = document.getElementById("pretend");
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    counter++;
    var nextWidth = parseInt(tmpWindow.style.width) - (10 * counter);
    tmpWindow.style.width = nextWidth + "px";
  });
});
```

```css
.test-window {
  /*width: 700px;*/
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.container-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container-right img {
  width: 100%;
}

.container-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="scale">Shrink window size</button>
</div>
<div id="pretend" class="test-window" style="width:700px;">
  <div class="container-right">
    <img id="img-right" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" />
  </div>
  <div class="container-left">
    <p>Dante, astray in a wood, reaches the foot of a hill which he begins to ascend; he is hindered by three beasts; he turns back and is met by Virgil, who proposes to guide him into the eternal world. Midway upon the road of our life I found myself within
      a dark wood, for the right way had been missed. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```